# Bash script in C language for android ndk

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I have a problem with this:
C code

```
#define CREATE_HTML_FILE_SCRIPT "/bin/curl https://coinmarketcap.com/it/currencies/bytecoin-bcn/ > /data/data/com.example.bytecoin/bcn.html"

#define CREATE_TEMP_FILE_SCRIPT "/data/local/lynx /data/data/com.example.bytecoin/bcn.html -dump > /data/data/com.example.bytecoin/bcn.txt"

system(CREATE_HTML_FILE_SCRIPT);
system(CREATE_TEMP_FILE_SCRIPT);
```

If I run from adb shell these commands all works well but when these command are executed from the app, file.html and file.txt are empty... I don't understand why and how I can solve it.

Comment: I think one of two things may be happening. One is you may have a permissions issue where you are trying to write these files on the devices storage. Two is that, perhaps you need to specify the full path to read and write to/from. 

Also, since you are executing Linux command line arguments. Maybe specify the location of the executables for curl and lynx as well. Such as /usr/bin/curl *link* > /my/directory/file.html etc..

Comment: Why not found a way to get stdout/stderr and check for errors?

Comment: @Lkabo I tried specifying the location of the executables for curl and lynx but I get the same behavior...

Comment: @Lkabo I have root on my phone so I have all permissions right? WHen I execute those two strings with adb shell they work perfectly, but in the app they create empty files.

Comment: i am wondering if the app is executing the commands with root access?

Comment: @Lkabo I don't know if it does, how do I let the app execute commands with root access? Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: You could try adding sudo to the start of the command. Not sure if it would work in that environment but it’s worth a shot. 

IE: system("sudo lynx file.html -dump > file.txt");

Comment: But as @emandt stated, it would be helpful to get some output of whatever error is occurring also.

Comment: @Lkabo nothing changed with sudo too :(

Comment: @Lkabo How can I get output of the errors?

Comment: Hook up your phone to your computer and run the app from android studio. It has a log that you can watch and will output a ton of info. The key should be in there somewhere.

Comment: Use absolute path instead

Comment: @S Dao what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Well, lynx is an interactive program, so I think you'll run in trouble when using it from a `system()` call.  But not with `curl`:

```
/* pru_curl-1.c */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *cmd = "curl https://www.google.com/";

    system(cmd); /* you will get the output of curl on stdout */

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is with curl redirecting its output in the shell call with the `>` operator:

```
/* pru_curl-2.c */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *cmd = "curl https://www.google.com/ >output_file-2";

    /* you will get the output of curl on output_file-2 */
    system(cmd);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Curl, on the other side, allows you to specify `-o output_file.txt` and you'll be able to read the file, once the program has finished.

```
/* pru_curl-3.c */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *cmd = "curl https://www.google.com/ -o output_file-3";

    /* you will get the output of curl on output_file-3 */
    system(cmd);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

You have a third alternative, which is using `popen(3)`, that allows you to start the program as a subcommand, and read the output of that program from the `FILE *` descriptor you get from `popen(3)`.  You could use it like this (processing character by character):

```
/* pru_curl-4.c */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *cmd = "curl https://www.google.com/";

    FILE *f = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n",
            cmd, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        printf("[%d]", c); /* you will get the downloaded file as
                            * sequences of numbers (the character
                            * values) embedded in square brackets on
                            * stdout */
    }
    pclose(f);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

or (processing line by line):

```
/* pru_curl-5.c */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *cmd = "curl https://www.google.com/";

    FILE *f = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n",
            cmd, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f)) {
        /* you'll get your output in chunks of one line, or 256 bytes
         * ---if longer---, encapsulated by a pair of square brackets
         * drawn in a different color (gren, by the escape sequences
         * used) */
        fprintf(stderr,
            "\033[1;33m[\033[m%s\033[32m]\033[m",
            line);
    }
    pclose(f);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

or (by blocks):

```
/* pru_curl-6.c */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 8 /* blocks in buffer */
#define CPB 11 /* chars per block */

int main()
{
    char *cmd = "curl https://www.google.com/";

    FILE *f = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n",
            cmd, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char block[N][CPB];
    int n;
    char *sep = "";
    do {
        /* print a blanck line between groups */
        printf("%s", sep);
        sep = "\n";

        /* we read as many CPB byte blocks as possible to fill the
         * N registers in buffer.
         * Then we start again until we don't fill completely the
         * buffer. */
        n = fread(block, sizeof block[0], N, f);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("[%.*s]\n", (int)sizeof block[i], block[i]);
        }

        printf("finished one loop of %d blocks of %d chars, each.\n",
                N, (int) sizeof block[0]);
    } while (n == N);
    /* n < N, so we are finished, check that probably the last register is
     * not printed because it was not complete. */
    pclose(f);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

(All these examples are complete and have been tested before posting)

---

## Edit

I have completed the code for the six programs and now all of them are executables with just building with:

```
$ cc pru_curl-<i>.c -o pru_curl-<i>   # <i> is the program number
$ _
```

In each case, you can execute the program by just running:

```
$ pru_curl-<i>
....  <-- a lot of output (or to a file) about the contents of the root page of google.
$ _
```

Comment: I tried curl with -o but nothing changed, and I use lynx with -dump so it isn't interactive... I don't understand why it doesn't work, I tried with popen too but it doesn't work

Comment: @xcocco, believe me that saying _it doesn't work_ is not enough.  I have tested my code before posting, so please, document what does it mean _it doesn't work_ for you.  What is **what you expect the code to do** and **what is what you get instead.**

Comment: I know this code works with linux programs but when this code is executed from the android app this code doesn't work... Doesn't work for me means it doesn't do what I should do because when this code is running from linux program it fills files with whatever you said it to but from the android app it creates empty files.

Comment: Probably you have the standard output already redirected to somewhere else when you call the program.  Android has a linux kernel, so no much diference in behaviour is expected. The `popen` solution gives you the opportunity of redirecting the output to your program as I did with all the programs that use it.  But again, _doesn't work_ is the only thing you seem you be able to say.

Comment: I didn't want to look bad against you, sorry for that, anyway if stream is redirected to somewhere else, why does it create empty files wherever I said it to? Thanks for your answers

Comment: The `-o outputFile` should work anyway.  You should check why the program was not capable of creating the output file, probably a permission problem.  Did you create it in a proper place?

Comment: Try to run the command you are issuing with `system()` in the same scenario as your program does. but calling it from a shell (from a bourne shel, `/bin/sh`, as that is the shell called by `system()`).  The `system()` function just spawns a shell `/bin/sh` and passes the string you passed to it as input to that shell.  If you make a mistake in the command, you should get the shell error on standard error.

Comment: BTW can you post exactly what string are you passing to `system()`?  The shell interpreting your command is sensible to shell metacharacters, so if you have put something strange in your url, that could be the problem.

Comment: I alredy ran in shell and it works, I'm going to edit the question putting the exact string in system, thank you

Comment: Are you sure `curl` is located in `/bin` directory.  Is'n it in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: yes I'm sure ```curl``` is located in ```/bin```

Comment: That sounds strange... as normally all non essential to boot programs are normally installed in `/usr`, instead of `/`.

Comment: I don't know what to say

Comment: I don't know  either :) what do you want me to do? I've spent more than two working hours with your problem, but we reached a point in which you give me no more feedback to make a diagnostic.  So I cannot provide you more to you.   The six examples I have written all work without any problem.  It's clear that something must be happening to cause that behaviour, but I don't know what is it.  The programs I wrote just require the standard `libc` to be installed, with is a mandatory issue in almost every system.  So only a permissions problem can be, which you don't seem to have investigated.

Comment: Probably you're right, but it doesn't make sense so much because the directory I'm writing is the only one having permissions from the app so I don't know how to solve this